# how to update a textbox from a static class?

Tags: java, class, static, non-static

This is driving me nuts.   I have a working text based application.  It has many many variables which now need a GUI.  I'm starting with the basics. Whenever some data is sent to my log, I want it to display in my textbox.

Here is a unified entry point for data to pass where it can be manipulated.

```
public class Log {

    private static void consoleOut(String data) {
    System.out.println(data);
    OBD2nerConsole.update(data);
    }
      public static void level0(String data) {
    if (Status.ConsoleLevel >= 0) {
    consoleOut(data);

    }
```

This is my form and it has a text box and a few buttons.

```
public class OBD2nerConsole extends java.awt.Frame {

    public static void update(String data) {
        textField1.setText(textField1.getText() + data);
    }   

}
```

The prolem I am having is that I am working with a static and non-static I guess..  There is nothing displayed in the text box.  I kept playing around and removed all of the errors but it is not working.  I don't really know what to do.  It seems that this is the best configuration, because there are no errors, but the text box is not doing anything.

I should probly add that this is my first form EVER!

Comment: It may be worth looking at log4j-swing-appender for inspiration: http://code.google.com/p/log4j-swing-appender/  The authors have likely gone through a lot of the design issues you are facing.  The Subversion commit comments http://code.google.com/p/log4j-swing-appender/source/list would be good for linking intent with code change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give *Log* a static reference to an instance of *OBD2nerConsole* and remove **static** from *update(String)* you should be able to update the **textField1**.

Listing of modified `Log.java`:

```
public class Log {
    private static Updatable console = Updatables.getUpdatable();

    private static void consoleOut(String data) {
        System.out.println(data);
        console.update(data);
    }

    public static void level0(String data) {
        if (Status.ConsoleLevel >= 0) {
            consoleOut(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Listing of `Updatable.java`:

```
public interface Updatable {
    void update(String);
}
```

Listing of modified snippet of `ODB2nerConsole.java`:

```
public class OBD2nerConsole extends java.awt.Frame implements Updatable {
    @Override
    public void update(String data) {
        textField1.setText(textField1.getText() + data);
    }
}
```

Listing of `Updatables.java`:

```
public class Updatables {
    public Updatable getUpdatable() {
        return new ODB2nerConsole();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok.  how about if I want to create that object from somewhere else other then my log?  Do I have to create a new instance of it?  or will my log become my synchronizer after this?  

Basically, I was hoping instead of creating a new, I could use existing information to update the form.

Comment: Certainly :)  You could add an interface called Updatable that has a method update(String) and have ODB2nerConsole implement it.  Then a third-party like Updatables could provide [public static Updatable getUpdatable()] which returns a ODB2nerConsole instance.  I imagine this is descending into greek right about now, so I'll chill.

Comment: wow.  that IS Greek.  Have I just dealt in VB for too long, or is there a way to say: Console.TextField1.setText("my arbitrary text");

Comment: I set up  public static OBD2nerConsole console = new OBD2nerConsole();  in public class Status which is where all of my globals are kept.  Is there a way I can now manipulate that somehow from my static classes?   It does not seem to want to be manipulated.  Everything is going through as it should, but nothing happens when I send data from the static classes to the form.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `textField1` is an attribute of the parent class, the `update` method should not be `static`.  That of course means that you need to apply the method to an instance of the `ODB2tunerConsole` object.

The rule in Java is that a `static` method cannot access the non-static attributes and methods of its class with explicitly using a reference to an instance of the class.

This leads people who are new to object-oriented programming in Java to try to make everything static.  But as you see, that leads to trouble.  The correct solution is to limit your use of statics to cases where they are really needed.  These are as follows:

- Shared constants; e.g. `public static final String FOO = "foo";`
- Helper methods that depend only on the state of their arguments.
- Hidden references to global data structures, exposed (if necessary) using the "singleton" pattern.